# Install Cpanel / Plesk on a didcated server

Tags: cpanel, plesk

is it risky to install plesk or cpanel on a dedicated server with many sites already set up ?

Actually there is more than 800 websites already configured (handmade website) and 30 wordpress.

Everyhting is already configured : vhosts, cron, fail2ban, directories, ....

Answer (score 1):

When you install a panel over an existing configuration, your configuration will not be imported into the panel, but most likely it will be wiped. You should not install a panel over an existing installation.

Instead, spin-up a new server, install a fresh Plesk on it and add their free "Website Importer" extension. With that you can easily import existing websites and mailboxes from another server. Plesk, too, supports migration from many different other panels, so if you are currently using a different panel, chances are you can simply migrate the whole setup into Plesk.